# Why is `logBase 10 x` slower than `log x / log 10`, even when specialized?

Tags: optimization, haskell, ghc

`solrize` in #haskell asked a question about one version of this code and I tried some other cases and was wondering what was going on. On my machine the "fast" code takes ~1 second and the "slow" code takes ~1.3-1.5 (everything is compiled with `ghc -O2`).

```
import Data.List

log10 :: Double -> Double
--log10 x = log x / log 10 -- fast
--log10 = logBase 10 -- slow
--log10 = barLogBase 10 -- fast
--log10 = bazLogBase 10 -- fast
log10 = fooLogBase 10 -- see below

class Foo a where
    fooLogBase :: a -> a -> a

instance Foo Double where
    --fooLogBase x y = log y / log x -- slow
    fooLogBase x = let lx = log x in \y -> log y / lx -- fast


barLogBase :: Double -> Double -> Double
barLogBase x y = log y / log x

bazLogBase :: Double -> Double -> Double
bazLogBase x = let lx = log x in \y -> log y / lx


main :: IO ()
main = print . foldl' (+) 0 . map log10 $ [1..1e7]
```

I'd've hoped that GHC would be able to turn `logBase x y` into exactly the same thing as `log y / log x`, when specialised. What's going on here, and what would be the recommended way of using `logBase`?

Comment: ghc could be doing constant propagation of `log 10` in some cases. Try measuring with a variable base.

Comment: n.b. The `Floating` instance for `Double` defines `logBase` equivalently to the commented out definition of `fooLogBase` above.

Comment: They're all equally fast when you compile with the LLVM backend.

Answer (score 22):

As always, look at the Core.

Fast (1.563s) -

```
-- note: top level constant, referred to by specialized fooLogBase

Main.main_lx :: GHC.Types.Double
Main.main_lx =
     case GHC.Prim.logDouble# 10.0 of { r ->
     GHC.Types.D# r
  }

Main.main7 :: GHC.Types.Double -> GHC.Types.Double
Main.main7 =
  \ (y :: GHC.Types.Double) ->
    case y of _ { GHC.Types.D# y# ->
    case GHC.Prim.logDouble# y# of { r0 ->
    case Main.main_lx of { GHC.Types.D# r ->
    case GHC.Prim./## r0 r of { r1 ->
    GHC.Types.D# r1
    }
    }
    }
```

Slow (2.013s)

```
-- simpler, but recomputes log10 each time
Main.main7 =
  \ (y_ahD :: GHC.Types.Double) ->
    case y_ahD of _ { GHC.Types.D# x_aCD ->
    case GHC.Prim.logDouble# x_aCD of wild1_aCF { __DEFAULT ->
    case GHC.Prim.logDouble# 10.0 of wild2_XD9 { __DEFAULT ->
    case GHC.Prim./## wild1_aCF wild2_XD9 of wild3_aCz { __DEFAULT ->
    GHC.Types.D# wild3_aCz
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

In the fast version, log10 is computed once and shared (the static argument is applied once only). In the slow version it is recomputed each time.

You can follow this line of reasoning to produce even better versions:

```
-- 1.30s
lx :: Double
lx = log 10

log10 :: Double -> Double
log10 y = log y / lx

main :: IO ()
main = print . foldl' (+) 0 . map log10 $ [1..1e7]
```

And, using array fusion, you can remove the penalty of the compositional style:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V

lx :: Double
lx = log 10

log10 :: Double -> Double
log10 y = log y / lx

main :: IO ()
main = print . V.sum . V.map log10 $ V.enumFromN 1 (10^7)
```

Cutting the cost by 3x

```
$ time ./A
6.5657059080059275e7

real    0m0.672s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Which is as good as writing it by hand. The below offers no benefit over the correctly written version above.

```
lx :: Double
lx = D# (GHC.Prim.logDouble# 10.0##)

log10 :: Double -> Double
log10 (D# y) = D# (case logDouble# y of r -> r /## d#)
    where
        D# d# = lx

main :: IO ()
main = print . V.sum . V.map log10 $ V.enumFromN 1 (10^7)
```

Comment: That's really poor of ghc.  Warrants a ticket.

Comment: GHC seems to consider `logBase# 10` so cheap that it doesn't float it out, though it actually matters here. And there are no special rewrite rules for logarithms (so no constant folding).

Comment: That's a bug. The various elementary functions need to be constant folded or floated.

Comment: The question wasn't particularly about how to optimize this meaningless program, it was about why `logBase` was slower. :-) I figured out that the log10 value wasn't being shared -- see the difference between the two `fooLogBase`s -- but I'm not sure why not, and how to write reasonable code that still ensures that it gets shared.

Comment: Just use an explicit `let` to guarantee sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Another missed optimization: dividing by a constant (log 10) should be replaced with multiplying by the reciprocal.

Comment: Careful. That can change the result.